# Performance difference between EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_ID) vs. MONTH(DATE_ID)?

Tags: sql, exasol

I have a table with a lot of columns and a few million rows.

One colum has column type "DATE":

| DATE_ID |
| --- |
| 2022-10-01 |
| 2022-10-02 |
| 2022-10-03 |
| ... |

Exasol does manage indexes itself so you can't set one.

When I need the month of the date is it better to use

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_ID)
```

or to use

```
MONTH(DATE_ID)
```

in terms of performance?

https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/extract.htm
https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/month.htm

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if after statement compilation there is no difference.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Docu for MONTH(): "This function can also be applied on strings, in contrast to function EXTRACT." -> so I thought that maybe EXTRACT() is faster for DATE columns and MONTH() is faster for VARCHAR columns?

Answer (score 1):

### Indexes in Exasol

> Exasol does set manage indexes itself, you can't set one.

You can set indexes manually with the `ENFORCE` statement, but this is not recommended. See [Manual Index Creation](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/performance/best_practices.htm#ManualIndexCreation).

However, an index on e.g. `MONTH(DATE_ID)` is an expression index. Such an index might be created during a join, but it will never be stored persistently. This means it will be recreated every time the query runs. If performance is a problem, it might be better to create a separate column with the month. If you use this column during a join, Exasol will create a persistent index on this column that can be reused. See [Indexes](https://exasol.my.site.com/s/article/Indexes) for more information.

### MONTH vs. EXTRACT

`MONTH` does add an implicit cast to `TIMESTAMP`, so there might be a slight performance advantage for `EXTRACT` which doesn't add a cast. In most queries, this won't be a significant difference.